# GWT Serialization error

Tags: gwt, serialization

in my app I faced a problem when reloading some pages. The error is:

```
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find class com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.lang.Long_FieldSerializer
```

I've downloaded gwt sources and found that error is caused by this line:

```
Class<?> klass = ReflectionHelper.loadClass(typeHandlerClass);
```

in file `com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/impl/SerializerBase.java`

When we navigate to the page with hyper links or enter url manually everything works perfect, the code above is working, the class is loaded. But when we hit F5 button on some pages, the exception appears.

Comment: Are you sure you have included gwt-servlet.jar in classpath ( i.e under WEB-INF/lib )? Also if your are in GWT 2.5 move to GWT 2.5.1 and start over again with fresh set up ( clear temp/cache files )

Comment: Did you try the suggested checks?

Comment: I checked the WEB-INF/lib, the file is there. What about upgrading GWT, this bug first appeared back on version 1.7, so is it worth to try upgrade?

Comment: Yes. But upgrade from 1.7 will itself bring several challenges :) . Of course GWT since 2.0 is seriously rocking and you are missing the performance optimizations since then upto 2.5 !!!!

Comment: Note - its pretty hard to track down bugs from gwt 1.7 which was released 4 years ago in 2009 !!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [GWT Custom Field Serialization Issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15070383/gwt-custom-field-serialization-issue)